# Specific Bootstrap 5 grid system logic for future Wordpress post thumbnail output

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I'm making website on Bootstrap 5. And need to make such grid system for product thumbnails (picture below).
[image: Specific grid system]

My idea(logic) to make this grid like this (picture below). This grid will be responsive for mobile devices.
[image: My logic]

And here's code for this idea.

```html
    <main class="py-3">
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row gy-2">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="row gy-2 row-cols-1">
                            <div class="col px-1">
                                <div class="card border-0">
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col px-1">
                                <div class="card border-0">
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 px-1">
                        <div class="card border-0">
                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row gy-2 row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2">
                    <div class="col px-1">
                        <div class="card border-0">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col px-1">
                        <div class="card border-0">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col px-1">
                        <div class="card border-0">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
```

But I think, that such logic will be difficult to output in Wordpress code (I'm not sure that this grid could be done by "while" loop).
Maybe there are other solutions?

Comment: @isherwood. I'm add my code. But my question was not about code only, but for all my logic building such grid for Wordpress output code.

Comment: Then your question should include our attempt at _that_ (or it should be at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @isherwood, I didn't start write code for Wordpress output for this grid yet (I wrote code only for another, much simplier grid). That why I asked about logic (not the exact code) for this grid. Because I want make right frontend part at start. Maybe there is a simpler logic for building such grid than the one I made.